# Log monitoring shell script to grep a string and send email alert

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, scripting, monitoring

Here is the `grep` line that is not working

```
grep -i "`date --date='today' '+%b %e'`"/ora/n003/OSB2/WLS_OSB2-diagnostic.log | awk '{ $3=""; print}' | egrep -wi 'failed' >>  $MESSAGE
```

The string it looks for is "failed" and once found, it should send an email. But it doesn't do this. I am not getting the expected response ,which is to send the specific string, in this case "FAILED" error messages in the log file to my email address. Now, I get an empty email content.

Below is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

#turn on debug mode
set -x
for f in *
do
    file $f
done
#Set the variable which equal to zero

#LOG_PATH="/ora/n004/test//OSB2/WLS_OSB2-diagnostic.log"

#prev_count=0

#grep -i "failed" /ora/n004/test/OSB2/WLS_OSB2-diagnostic.log  | wc -w

grep -i "`date --date='today' '+%b %e'`"/ora/n004/test/OSB2/WLS_OSB2-diagnostic.log | awk '{ $3=""; print}' | egrep -wi 'failed' >>  $MESSAGE


#if [ "$prev_count" -lt "$count" ] ; then

# Send a mail to given email id when errors found in log

SUBJECT="WARNING: Errors found in log on "`date --date='today' '+%b %e'`""

# This is a temp file, which is created to store the email message.

MESSAGE="This is a test!!There is a timeout"

TO="somebody@gmail.com"

echo "ATTENTION: Errors are found in /ora/n004/test//OSB2/WLS_OSB2-diagnostic.log. Please Check with int team." >> $MESSAGE

echo  "Hostname: `hostname`" >> $MESSAGE

echo -e "\n" >> $MESSAGE

echo "+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+" >> $MESSAGE

echo "Error messages in the log file as below" >> $MESSAGE

echo "+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+" >> $MESSAGE

#grep -i "`date --date='today' '+%b %e'`"/ora/n004/test//OSB2/WLS_OSB2-diagnostic.log | awk '{ $3=""; print}' | egrep -wi 'failed' >>  $MESSAGE

mailx -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < $MESSAGE


#rm $MESSAGE
```

NOTE: I have comment out some of the lines that are not been used..

Thanks.

Comment: 1/2 What do you mean by the `grep` line "_is not working_"? It almost certainly is working, unless you got an error message, just that it's probably not doing what you expect. Tell us (in your question) what your program is supposed to do, and what happened instead. Don't forget to include error messages and any attempts you've made to fix the problem yourself. Did you know you can catch quite a number of errors by pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net/ ? It's probably also worth completely removing the lines that you're not using, so it's easier for us to understand what's going on

Comment: 2/2 Think about where you use `$MESSAGE` and also where you define it. From they way you mostly use it, it seems like it's supposed to be a file _name_, so review of what you set it to.

Comment: Hi Roaima, am not getting the expected response ,which is to send the specific string, in this case "FAILED" error messages in the log file to my email address. Now, i get an empty email content.

Comment: As for the $MESSAGE, yes, it was supposed to be a file name, but i have changed it to just a text that says "This is a Test!"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide updates. Do not write in the comments as it then is harder for people to track the full detail of the question

Comment: Have you pasted your code into shellcheck.net yet? If not, please do so, fix the errors, try the solution again, and update your question as appropriate with the latest information that you have. There's no issue doing this as you've got no answers yet.